# Relate the indixes (keys) of an Array object to the indixes (keys) of an array (PHP)

Tags: php

I have a doubt in which I didn't get a solution. I have an Array `values` ​​object and a `status` array, where I want to relate the indixes of the Array `values` ​​object to the indixes of the `status` array. So that I can write a logical test where: **If the Array `values` ​​object's index `0` is different from `null` (that is, it contains value), then the `status` array's index `0` will get the value "1".**

OR

**If the Array `values` ​​object's index `1` is different from `null` (that is, it contains value), then the `status` array's index `1` will receive the value "1".**

For example, before the logic test:

```
values:[
 0 => Array1:[
  0 => "1,023"
  1 => "0,023"
  2 => "5,023"
  3 => "1"
 ]
 1 => Array2:[
  0 => "null"
  1 => "null"
  2 => "5"
  3 => "1,365"
 ]
 2 => Array3:[
  0 => "null"
  1 => "null"
  2 => "null"
  3 => "null"
 ]
]


status:[
 0 => "0"
 1 => "0"
 2 => "0"
]
```

After the logical test:

```
status:[
 0 => "1"
 1 => "0"
 2 => "0"
]
```

**In this example, only the index `0` of the `status` array received the value "1", because ONLY the `0` array of the Array `values` ​​object had values ​​other than `null`.**

---

The `status` array will always have the same number of indixes as the Array `values` ​​object will have for arrays **(If the `status` array has 5 indices (0, 1, 2, 3, 4), the Array `value` object will have 5 arrays (0, 1, 2 , 3, 4))**. Furthermore, the `status` array will always start with the value of the index values ​​equal to "0". **And if the values ​​of the `values` ​​object's indices are ALL different from null, each index of the `status` array will receive the value "1".**

For example,

```
status:[
 0 => "1",
 1 => "1",
 2 => "1",
]
```

**I believe I would have to iterate through the `value` array object with a `foreach` and do a logical test to see which ones are `null`, but I don't know how to change the value of the `status` array.**

I hope I was clear in my doubt.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: In your example `null` is the special value represents a variable with no value or is the string word `'null'`?

Comment: _"but I don't know how to change the value of the status array."_ - `$status[some_index] = ...;`? And `some_index` would the same index as the one of the `values` element you are currently iterating over.

Comment: You may have your data types confused. The string `"null"` is a value, do you want to check for the string `"null"` or no value, i.e. the data type `null` ?

Comment: Also, from reading the question, I can't figure out when you actually want to return the value `1` and when you want to return the value `0`? Do you want to return `0` if there is one or more instances of `null` in the array? Or if the value in index position `0` is null?

Comment: @nagiyevel 
represents a null variable

Comment: @AndrewHardiman
yes, check the string null

Comment: @AndrewHardimanI want to return 0, when there is a null inside the index. Or return 1 when there is no null within the index.

Comment: @AndrewHardimanIf it has a null inside the index, it returns 0. If it doesn't have any null inside the index, it returns 1. As I had exemplified.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing and reading many PHP documents, I managed to solve my problem.

```
foreach ($values as $key => $items) {
    if (in_array(null, $items)) {
        $status['status'][$key] = "0";
    } else {
        $status['status'][$key] = "1";
    }
}
```

When I give a `dd($status)` I get confirmation of the desired change.

```
"status" => [
 0 => "1"
 1 => "0"
 2 => "0"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have added a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Now that you've answered the question makes sense. However, I would recommend a change.

If you want to run the suggested answer:

```php
foreach ($values as $key => $items) {
    if (in_array(null, $items)) {
        $status['status'][$key] = "0";
    } else {
        $status['status'][$key] = "1";
    }
}
```

you will run into edge cases when `$items` array contains empty values meaning `[]`, `null`, `false`, `0` or `''`.

If you consider the following values:

```php
$values = [
    ['1,023', '0,023', '5,023', '1'],
    [null, null, 5, 1, 365],
    [null, null, null, null, null],
    ['1,023', '0,023', '5,023', ''],
];
```

the `$status` you'll get is:

```php
[
    'status' => [
        0 => '1', 
        1 => '0', 
        2 => '0', 
        3 => '0',   // probably wanted '1'
    ]
];
```

This is because `in_array` as is, does a **loose** comparison meaning `==` in this case `null == ''` is `true`. To correct this you should use the 3rd parameter. And do a **strict** comparison:

```php
foreach ($values as $key => $items) {
    if (in_array(null, $items, true)) { // notice true
        $status['status'][$key] = "0";
    } else {
        $status['status'][$key] = "1";
    }
}
```

Putting in the same values we get:

```php
[
    'status' => [
        0 => '1', 
        1 => '0', 
        2 => '0', 
        3 => '1',
    ]
];
```

Comment: Ok, I will increment this suggested change. Thank you very much.